# PHP unsets class variables when PDO exception occurs

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, exception

I just found out this happening on some scripts I have written.  Feels very wierd to me.  When a PDO exception occurs, in the exception handler I cannot access class variables.

I am using: 
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 (cli) (built: Oct 28 2015 01:34:46)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies

```
class myClass extends PDO {
    var $myVar
    public function __construct ($text) {
        $this->myVar = $text."_Hello";
        echo $this->myVar;
        try {
            //try to connect to db here
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            echo $this->myVar;
            die;
        }
    }
}
```

So when the connection fails (in this case error was too many connections) even though the first echo $myVar works, the one in the catch block gives me 'PHP Notice:  Undefined variable:'

If I change to this though, it works fine:

```
class myClass extends PDO {
    var $myVar
    public function __construct ($text) {
        $anotherVar = $text."_Hello";
        echo $anotherVar;
        try {
            //try to connect to db here
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            echo $anotherVar;
            die;
        }
    }
}
```

I obviously though need the global variable for use in other functions.  Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: if in your catch you put only `var_dump($this); exit;` you have the same undefined error ?

Comment: Sorry, Ryan Vincent, my bad while writing the code here.

Comment: @Bob0t just tried the var_dump and it returns null.

Comment: @Ryan Vincent - The $anotherVar one is actually fine. It is the one using $this->myVar which isn't.  Also $anotherVar is created outside the try.

Comment: @Bob0t - I tried var_dump before the try, in the try and in the catch.  It works fine everywhere except the catch.

Comment: FWIW, it's not typically a great idea to `extend PDO`, unless you know exactly how the `PDO` class works internally. You should rather simply instantiate a `new PDO` inside of `myClass`, or preferably inject it as constructor argument.

Comment: Also, how exactly are you `trying to connect here`?

Comment: @MarkA.Tagliaferro I just understood what happen :') In fact its fully logic. You extend PDO, so if your `parrent::__construct()` fails, the construct itself fails, so `null` it set into `$this`, not really clear, I hope you understand what I mean. Better as deceze said, Doing a warpper & some magic like using `__call()` to check & try to call PDO funcs once instantiated into a class var.

Comment: Example of extending a class - declaring properties and local variables and seeing where they are available. https://eval.in/625698